# Generate a WSDL without a webserver

Tags: c++, visual-studio, wsdl

I would like to generate a WSDL file from a c++ atl webservice without using a web server.  I would like to generate it as part of the visual studio build or as a post build event.  I found a program ([CmdHelper](http://www.stephan-brenner.com/?page_id=82)) that does this for .NET assemblies but it doesn't seem to work for what I need.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Microsoft SOAP Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=c943c0dd-ceec-4088-9753-86f052ec8450&displaylang=en) comes with a WSDL generator, which will generate a WSDL file from a COM component.  We use that where I work, and it seems to do the job.  We haven't tried to integrate it into our build process - we've always run the tool by hand when we need to update the WSDL, and we check the generated WSDL into version control.

I see that Microsoft has deprecated this product, so there may be newer alternatives out there, but it works fine for us.